# Extracting data from complicated associative array in php and put into new array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have an complicated array that looks like this:

```
$input=array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'XXX' => array(
            'id' => '7',
            'p_id' => '1',
            'address' => '9463',
            'arrival_time' => '2014-05-01 03:30:00'
        ),
        'YYY' => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'iden' => '1111',
            'name' => 'Tom'
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'XXX' => array(
            'id' => '9',
            'p_id' => '2',
            'address' => '9469',
            'arrival_time' => '2014-05-27 16:43:58'
        ),
        'YYY' => array(
            'id' => '2',
            'iden' => '2222',
            'name' => 'Sam'
        )
    ),
    (int) 2 => array(
        'XXX' => array(
            'id' => '3',
            'p_id' => '3',
            'address' => '9462',
            'arrival_time' => '2014-04-21 14:05:00'
        ),
        'YYY' => array(
            'id' => '3',
            'iden' => '3333',
            'name' => 'James'
        )
    )
)
```

I would like to convert it such that it looks like this;

```
$output=array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'name' => 'Tom',
        'iden' => '1111',
        'address' => '9463'
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'name' => 'Sam',
        'iden' => '2222',
        'address' => '9469'
    ),
    (int) 2 => array(
        'name' => 'James',
        'iden' => '3333',
        'address' => '9462'
    )
```

I wrote some code to solve this problem:

```
foreach ( $input as $key => $value)
{
    $output['name']=$input[$key]['YYY']['name'];
    $output['iden']=$input[$key]['YYY']['iden'];
    $output['address']=$input[$key]['XXX']['address'];
}
```

Unfortunately, it retrieves only the last element of the input array.

Can someone more experienced help?

Thank you very much.

Comment: To define an array it is not necessary to use `(int) 0 => `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overwriting the values in each iteration, as you always write to `$output['name']` etc.

```
foreach ( $input as $key => $value)
{
    $output[$key] = array(
        'name' => $value['YYY']['name'],
        'iden' => $value['YYY']['iden'],
        'address' => $value['XXX']['address']
    );
}
```

The key here is using `$output[$key]` instead of `$output` - this way you will add a new element in each iteration.

Also `$input[$key]` and `$value` are equivalent, so I used the shorter variant ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your foreach loop :-

```
foreach ( $input as $key=>$value)
{
    $output[$key]['name']=$value['YYY']['name'];
    $output[$key]['iden']=$value['YYY']['iden'];
    $output[$key]['address']=$value['XXX']['address'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an index to the array in the foreach: $output[$key]["name"] = ...;